# Scheduled Task Time Constraint

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I've read through a few posts on SO on whether to use a Windows Service or Scheduled Task and from my understanding I should be using a Scheduled Task.

I have a simple program, basically do a little logic and send an email. The only hard requirement that I have is the email must be sent on the `:40` minute mark of each hour. So 8:40, 9:40, 10:40, etc. When I initially setup the schedule for the task I can set it to start at 8:40, recur every hour, every day.

That seems to fulfill the requirement but should I be worried about anything in regards to ensuring the task is ran on that schedule?

It all seems so simple that I'm sure I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well few points to mention

- If you are using a batch file make sure other programs can replace or change it.
- Use and access log to log whether the execution was successful or not so you can monitor later(Debugging you application)
- Use schedule task errors to check whether your application ran correctly (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558)
- Use as few privileges as possible.(which is the default)